# How can I change the VS2012 tab font size and whitespace?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2012, fonts, tabs, size

I like having a lot of files open in Visual Studio 2012, but they keep getting pushed off screen. This is because the font is too big and there is a lot of wasted real estate around the tab names. I'd like to shrink the font and get rid of the white space so I can open more tabs.

Comment: Press CTRL and spin the wheel of your mouse

Comment: That only resizes the text inside the window. I want the tab header text to be smaller because I want more headers to fit on my desktop.